# Filter syslog message with logstash grok filter

Tags: logstash

I have the following logs sent to logstash via syslog input (the logs come from docker containers sent to logstash via logspout)

So, in the following log sample, **the first line is a php-fpm error** and **the second line is a nginx access log**

```
docker-nginx-php-composer|2015/03/17 16:31:28 [error] 9#0: *41 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function teetstst() in /var/www/index.php on line 3" while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.10.37.110, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "turing:49213"
docker-nginx-php-composer|10.10.37.110 - - [17/Mar/2015:16:31:28 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 134 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36"
```

```

OK so now I want to filter all this mess so I can "tag" PHP-FPM logs for example or filter only the warning and errors of PHP-FPM ...

I suppose I have to use the `grok` filter from logstash but I don't know exactly how ?

let say I want to filter only PHP errors, put a "php" tag on it and also filter 404 and 500 errors from nginx, how can I achieve this easily with logstash/grok ?

Any clues ? examples ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would define two grok patterns:

1. php-fpm that starts with a date
2. nginx that starts with an ip

You can add_tag in each grok{} as desired.

Comment: ok thanks, is there any convenient way of testing grok filters ?
logstash runs as a service and for example if I want to test input from stdin and output to stdout, how  can I do that ?

Comment: Certainly using the debugger is a great way.